# Как включить в выражение фильтр картинок для правила nginx

Tags: nginx

есть выражение добавляющее слеш в конце url
оно действует и слеш добавляет, и к картинкам тоже,

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Вопрос: как исключить картинки (*.jpg, *.png) из этого правила?

адреса картинок

.ru/files/1769_content_img.jpg

Самостоятельно я нашел, как из действия (другого) правила убрать некоторые страницы, но это наверное не-то:

```
rewrite ^/((?!install|admin|administrator).*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Нужна ваша помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так попробуйте:

```
rewrite ^(?!.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$)(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Сначала идет просмотр вперед, чтобы на конце не было расширений jpeg, jpg, png, gif, а потом уже идет проверка на отсутствие слеша с захватом всей строки.

Comment: Все отлично заработало, спасибо!